# How to hide a class when a certain class is active?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how can I hide a certain class when another class is active,

The concept is surely clear but I am unable to code it.

So what I want to do basically is :

when class XYZ is active I want to hide class ABC.

oblige :)

Comment: Define "hide a class"

Comment: I cant understand that, sorry. Can you please code this piece for me?

Comment: @haim770 i'd suspect setting css "display:none". but what i'd like to get defined is "a class is active"…

Comment: @Nafees because there was nothing to understand… it was a question: "what do you mean by 'hide a class'" get a dictionary and look up "define". should be along the lines of 'stating the meaning of sth.'

Comment: @Nafees you should tell us what have you tried and what problems you are facing

Comment: Oh! I thought he is telling me to define something in javascript codes. and  I simply mean that when class1 is active then the class2 should be set to display:none

Comment: also, the problem is: the concept is surely unclear. because what is an in your terms "active class", and where are those classes? on the same element? scattered around the whole document? show us examples of what you're trying to achieve, and why you're unable to code it (=what doesn't work).

Comment: @NEO-xx I cannot code I have no idea where to start

Comment: yeah, but where is that class1? and how is it active? do you mean some link with `.class1:active`?

Comment: Sorry, but if you cannot code, then you should start learning how to if you want to do that. Reading and following some "getting started tutorial" will make much more sense for you than asking single questions here.

Comment: @Nafees your can start learning to code at codeacademy.com

Comment: Thankyou @nonchip Its something like toogle that when tab1 is active the tab2 or other tabs hide.

Comment: you could even do that with plain css…

Comment: and i'm pretty sure you don't want to hide a bunch of classes for that, cause it'll make your code pretty unportable. try something like "hide all tabs but the one selected" by iterating over them.

Comment: ok so `<div class="fb"> </div>` this has class fb now when i click this element the class becomes `<div class='fb_active' > </div>` now what I want is that there is an another element `<div class='tw'> </div>` so when the first element has class fb_active the element with class "tw" should be hidden

Comment: Then you can use my second solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33981460/3876196

Comment: also you should learn basic js before asking the SO to "please code this piece for me", cause we're no "i want some code, do it for free for me cause i'm too lazy" site, but trying to help with actual questions. and it'll help if you actually know what you're coding ;)

Comment: Ok nonchip surely next time I would be there to help someone thankyou for the tremendous help provided :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, by "hiding", you mean "removing" the class, here's a solution, using jQuery :

```
if (this.hasClass("XYZ"))
    this.removeClass("ABC");
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory, `hasClass` will check is the element has the class `XYZ`.

If by "hiding" the class, you mean "hiding the elements that have the class", also using jQuery :

```
if (this.hasClass("XYZ"))
    $(".ABC").hide()
```

Comment: but keep in mind the second code block needs jquery, not just plain JS

Comment: Thankyou I guess this will work, thanks for your suggestions :) 

By "needs jquery" you mean that this should be there in the head section right `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>` Lol I am a noob so please bare me

Comment: Yes indeed. jQuery is a library that will provide you extended functions for JavaScript. Your include will work.